# Wireshark not detect packets from java program in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, api, wireshark

I created a RESTful API in eclipse using java. I need to run it and capture HTTP packets using wireshark. However, wireshark not detect HTTP GETs or REQUESTs while executing the java program. Wireshark detects all other HTTP packets, for example from browsers.

Comment: Perhaps you're capturing on the wrong interface ? Perhaps you're using a non-standard port number, and have to tell wireshark that your port carries HTTP ? Perhaps you're using HTTPS ?

Comment: Thanks nos. It's seems that HTTPS is my problem.